# How to add jars from systempath in Docker

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

In my maven pom file I have some dependencies which are our own jar files from other projects which are not in repository.We have used 'system' scoped dependencies like

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>efaadmin</groupId>
        <artifactId>efaadmin</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>
        ${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\efaadmin.jar
        </systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Now when writing Dockerfile these dependencies have become our stumbling block.

```
#
# Build stage
#

FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-slim AS BUILD
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
COPY jars/*.jar /home/app/jars/
RUN  mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml

#
# Package stage
#
FROM tomcat:7.0-jdk8-openjdk-slim
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/DrySign.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ 
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/jars/* $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/xxxxx/WEB-INF/lib/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

But docker is complaining:

```
'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for efaadmin:efaadmin:jar must specify an absolute path but is ./jars/efaadmin.jar
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: Systempath causes many different problems and should be avoided if possible. Try to put everything into a Maven repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like an issue with Docker, it looks like an issue with Maven. Maven requires an absolute path for system scope dependencies.  You can test this is the case by commenting out all the lines of your Dockerfile below

```
...
RUN  mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml
# comment out everything below this, I think you'll still see the failure
```

By the way, why are you using backslashes not forward slashes for your `systemPath`?  Your Maven system scoped dependencies are being interpreted as relative paths, not absolute paths.  When you fix this, your build should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I can now build the Dockerfile. Here is my revised Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-slim AS BUILD
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
COPY jars/*.jar /home/app/jars/
ENV JAR_HOME /home/app/jars
RUN  mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean install


FROM tomcat:7.0-jdk8-openjdk-slim
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/DrySign.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ 
COPY --from=build /home/app/jars/*.jar $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```