# Cannot send mail from inside docker container

Tags: docker, email, smtp

I have a spring mvc application which I have dockerized. See this link [the way I dockerized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838461/how-to-add-jars-from-systempath-in-docker). Before containerization the ordinary war deployed in tomcat was able to send emails using host smtp.gmail.com and port 587.

My bean definition was like this:

```
<beans:bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <beans:property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <beans:property name="port" value="587" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="xxxxxx" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="xxxxx" />
    <beans:property name="javaMailProperties">
         <beans:props>
              <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</beans:prop>
              <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</beans:prop>
         </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Now I get this:

```
    org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused); message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
```

Comment: @Joshua I exposed port 587 & mail worked. Pl. may convert your comment to answer, so that I can accept the same.

Comment: I'll go ahead and delete my comment and formalize my answer for you. Thanks for the update

Comment: Facing same issue. Is this working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link you've provided and assuming that is exactly what you copied for your Dockerfile you'll need to expose an additional port for your mail client.

If you don't already know, by default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world.

In Dockerfiles you can use `EXPOSE`.
In your case you'll need
`EXPOSE 587` to enable communication for SMTP

Additionally, in the future if you need to expose other ports with different protocols you can use

`EXPOSE 587/tcp` (tcp is default)

If you want to read up more on `EXPOSE` I got my information from Docker Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Expose is for listening ports, not outgoing ports and it's more of documentation than anything...

from docker:
`
The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be`

Answer (score 0):

For me, actually installing ca-certificates and then,
restarting the container worked!